# using a USB A female - USB A female adapter

Tags: usb

I have s (supposively) normal A female to A female USB adapter. My original intent was to use it to connect my mobile devices to normal USB devices like mice and flash sticks. However, when I do use it (like with a mouse), there seems to be no active connection (the mouse sensor light doesn't turn on).

Now I would like to use it with a USB A-A male extender to be able to easily swap USB connections to a hub between my laptop and my computer. I know that using a USB A male-female extender would work, but I'm not sure if I have one. Does anyone know if it is possible to create a USB A male-female extension cable using the female-female adapter and male-male cable?

Comment: Your USB mouse will not work on a mobile device unless it supports a mouse.  Your question is awfully vague.

Comment: All mobile devices usually do support mice/keyboard (and even hubs), if one manages to turn the mobile device into host mode. A special "OTG adapter cable" is required, a Type-A receptacle with u-B cable, but with illegal short of ID pin to ground.

Comment: Some background: Most USB devices function in one of two modes: Master or slave. The computer typically is the master and uses and USB-A socket. Slaves usually use the USB-B (square) socket. You cannot connect master to master or slave to slave. (Well, you can with a weird cable, but it will not work).

The only exception seems to be some mobile devices which often use a special micro-AB connector which can switch modes. This is what Ali Chen refers to as USB on the go (OTG).

Comment: There are some DIY OTG adapter cable tutorials on YouTube. I will try to do it by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from @Hennes (original question):

> Some background: Most USB devices function in one of two modes: Master or slave. The computer typically is the master and uses and USB-A socket. Slaves usually use the USB-B (square) socket. You cannot connect master to master or slave to slave. (Well, you can with a weird cable, but it will not work). The only exception seems to be some mobile devices which often use a special micro-AB connector which can switch modes. This is what Ali Chen refers to as USB on the go (OTG).

Comment: This is tacky behavior; you don't deserve the upvotes for someone else's content.  The attribution is not sufficient.  If you consider the comment by @Hennes satisfactory for an answer, then ask him/her to post it as such.